# Creating a foreach keyword with yacc or Bison and Flex

Tags: c, foreach, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I have developed a interpreted programming language.  It is strongly based on C.  The problem is, I want to add a `foreach` directive and have no clue how to.

I am using Bison and Flex as the parser and lexer generator.

Comment: Your language will need to support the ability to get a containers size simply knowing the containers name. In C, arrays do not carry their size with them. So your language needs to make sure it supports this first.

Comment: General compiler (and interpreter) resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your grammar, you'd want an expression that is something like the following:

```
foreach := foreach ( name in name ) { statements }
```

When you parse this, you should be able to translate it directly into a while loop in your AST with an additional statement that assigns a variable at the beginning.

This seems to me the simplest way to do it, but will probably have limitations with multiple iterable data-types (e.g. a list vs. an array). In this case, you may want to consider consolidating all iterables so that they have a consistent method to obtain the next element.